Custom Postgres Dialect to migrate with Hibernate 6.x
I have this code to migrate with Hibernate 6.1.x and SpringBoot 3.3.4. I use
<hypersistence-utils-hibernate-63.version>3.9.0</hypersistence-utils-hibernate-63.version>

This is my class to convert:
import com.vladmihalcea.hibernate.type.array.IntArrayType;
import com.vladmihalcea.hibernate.type.array.LongArrayType;
import com.vladmihalcea.hibernate.type.array.StringArrayType;
import org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL10Dialect;
import org.hibernate.dialect.function.SQLFunctionTemplate;
import org.hibernate.dialect.function.StandardSQLFunction;
import org.hibernate.type.BigDecimalType;
import org.hibernate.type.IntegerType;
import org.hibernate.type.LongType;
import org.hibernate.type.StringType;

public class PostgresqlCustomDialect extends PostgreSQL10Dialect {

  public PostgresqlCustomDialect() {
    super();

    registerFunction("string_array",
        new StandardSQLFunction("array_agg", StringArrayType.INSTANCE));


    registerFunction("int_array",
        new StandardSQLFunction("array_agg", IntArrayType.INSTANCE));

    registerFunction("long_array",
        new StandardSQLFunction("array_agg", LongArrayType.INSTANCE));

    registerFunction("number_array",
        new StandardSQLFunction("array_agg", BigDecimalArrayType.INSTANCE));

    registerFunction("json_as_string", new SQLFunctionTemplate(StringType.INSTANCE,
        "?1  #>> '{}'"));

    registerFunction("json_attr_as_big_decimal", new JsonAttrGetter(BigDecimalType.INSTANCE));

    registerFunction("json_attr_as_string", new JsonAttrGetter(StringType.INSTANCE));

    registerFunction("json_attr_as_int", new JsonAttrGetter(IntegerType.INSTANCE));

    registerFunction("json_attr_as_long", new JsonAttrGetter(LongType.INSTANCE));
  }
}

I can't use the new Hibernate 6.x functions SqlFunctionMetadataBuilderContributor PostgresPlusDialect
Can you help me to migrate this code in Hibernate 6.x?
